# c++ class in one file

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am new to C++. For the moment I don't want to use separate compilation. But when I create a class in Eclipse it automatically creates the class.h and class.cpp. Which file can I use to write the whole class in without separate compilation?

Comment: You don't need separate compilations when you have two files with the same name. The compiler only compiles the *.cpp file. The *.h file only provides declarations, usually there's nothing to compile there (unless it's a template)

Comment: ...or inline function

Comment: You could bypass Eclipse's wizard, and make a blank cpp file, and write your code (including classes) there.

Answer (score 2):

Dividing files into `.h` and `.cpp` doesn't introduce separate compilation. All headers are included by source files.

When you `#include` a file, its contents are copied verbatim at the place of inclusion.

Thus, you should never include a `.cpp` file.
If you want to compile a file, pass it to the compiler.
If you both `#include` and compile a source file, you'll get multiple definition errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to declare and implement the class entirely in the .cpp file and simply delete the .h file.  You won't be able to use the class in other .cpp files, however, without a bunch of `extern` declarations.  For example:

```
// foo.cpp
#include <iostream>
class Foo
{
    Foo() { std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl; }
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Goodbye!" << std::endl; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example I made:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:

    Person()
    {

    }

   ~Person()
    {

    }

    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    void setName(string newName)
    {
        name  = newName;
    }

    int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    void setAge(int newAge)
    {
        age = newAge;
    }

    void toString()
    {
        cout << "Hello my name is " << name << ", and I'm " << age << " years old." << endl;
    }
private:
    string name;
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    Person p;
    p.setAge(20);
    p.setName("Bob");
    p.toString();
    return 0;
}
```

### OUTPUT

Hello my name is Bob, and I'm 20 years old.